# How to downgrade all updated packages?

Tags: updates, package-management

I use ubuntu 13.04 and that is not supported by Ubuntu so I change source.list to utopic and when run `apt-get update` , many packages to be updated , and I only run apt-get install cinnamon , this command removed some packages and upgrade another packaegs and install some new packages too. when the command is complete I restart my computer and cinnamon was ugly and unity not started , so I want to downgrade all updated packages but I do not know how to do it.
Relevant section of the /var/log/apt/history.log file

```
Start-Date: 2014-09-16  08:42:02
apt-get install cinnamon
Install: libzeitgeist-2.0-0:i386 (0.9.14-2.2ubuntu2, automatic), gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0:i386 (0.9.23-2ubuntu2, automatic), cheese-common:i386 (3.12.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), libjs-jquery:i386 (1.7.2+dfsg-3ubuntu2, automatic), libxcb-present-dev:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), cinnamon:i386 (2.2.16-3), libcinnamon-desktop4:i386 (2.2.3-2, automatic), libxcb-xfixes0-dev:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libmuffin0:i386 (2.2.6-2, automatic), python-pyatspi:i386 (2.10.0+dfsg-2, automatic), gir1.2-clutter-1.0:i386 (1.18.4-1, automatic), libgrilo-0.2-1:i386 (0.2.10-1, automatic), libgcr-base-3-1:i386 (3.12.2-1, automatic), cinnamon-settings-daemon:i386 (2.2.4.repack-2, automatic), libxcb-randr0:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), cinnamon-control-center:i386 (2.2.11-3, automatic), libmirclientplatform-mesa:i386 (0.7.2+14.10.20140912-0ubuntu1, automatic), libwayland-client0:i386 (1.5.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), cinnamon-common:i386 (2.2.16-3, automatic), nemo:i386 (2.2.4-1, automatic), gir1.2-caribou-1.0:i386 (0.4.14-1, automatic), gir1.2-json-1.0:i386 (1.0.2-1, automatic), libjson-glib-1.0-common:i386 (1.0.2-1, automatic), init-system-helpers:i386 (1.20ubuntu3, automatic), libmozjs185-1.0:i386 (1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-4.3, automatic), libcaribou-common:i386 (0.4.14-1, automatic), gir1.2-meta-muffin-0.0:i386 (2.2.6-2, automatic), libprotobuf8:i386 (2.5.0-9ubuntu1, automatic), libcjs0:i386 (2.2.2-2, automatic), libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libwebpmux1:i386 (0.4.1-1.1, automatic), libmirclient8:i386 (0.7.2+14.10.20140912-0ubuntu1, automatic), cinnamon-session:i386 (2.2.2-3, automatic), libcolord2:i386 (1.2.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), python-pil:i386 (2.5.3-1, automatic), cinnamon-session-common:i386 (2.2.2-3, automatic), libcogl-pango20:i386 (1.18.2-2, automatic), cinnamon-screensaver:i386 (2.2.4-5, automatic), libxcb-sync-dev:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libxcb-dri3-dev:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), muffin-common:i386 (2.2.6-2, automatic), libcheese-gtk23:i386 (3.12.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), libhogweed2:i386 (2.7.1-3, automatic), libmircommon1:i386 (0.7.2+14.10.20140912-0ubuntu1, automatic), libgcr-ui-3-1:i386 (3.12.2-1, automatic), libcinnamon-menu-3-0:i386 (2.2.0-2, automatic), cjs:i386 (2.2.2-2, automatic), libdb5.3:i386 (5.3.28-5, automatic), gir1.2-cogl-1.0:i386 (1.18.2-2, automatic), nemo-fileroller:i386 (1.8.0-1, automatic), libxcb-render0-dev:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libcogl20:i386 (1.18.2-2, automatic), mesa-utils:i386 (8.2.0-1, automatic), nemo-data:i386 (2.2.4-1, automatic), libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 (3.2.16-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxcb-randr0-dev:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libsystemd-login0:i386 (208-8ubuntu2, automatic), libxcb-sync1:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libevdev2:i386 (1.2.2+dfsg-1, automatic), cinnamon-desktop-data:i386 (2.2.3-2, automatic), libcogl-path20:i386 (1.18.2-2, automatic), libboost-system1.55.0:i386 (1.55.0+dfsg-1ubuntu3, automatic), libinput0:i386 (0.2.0-2, automatic), libxshmfence-dev:i386 (1.1-3, automatic), gir1.2-cinnamondesktop-3.0:i386 (2.2.3-2, automatic), libtotem-plparser18:i386 (3.10.2-3ubuntu1, automatic), libwayland-server0:i386 (1.5.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0:i386 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7, automatic), libgee-0.8-2:i386 (0.14.0-2, automatic), libxcb-present0:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), libwebp5:i386 (0.4.1-1.1, automatic), libxshmfence1:i386 (1.1-3, automatic), libllvm3.4:i386 (3.4.2-3ubuntu2, automatic), caribou:i386 (0.4.14-1, automatic), gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0:i386 (1.5.2-2, automatic), libcheese7:i386 (3.12.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0:i386 (0.6.37-1ubuntu9, automatic), gir1.2-polkit-1.0:i386 (0.105-4ubuntu2, automatic), libtasn1-6:i386 (4.0-2, automatic), libcaribou0:i386 (0.4.14-1, automatic), libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 (10.2.6-1ubuntu3, automatic), gir1.2-cmenu-3.0:i386 (2.2.0-2, automatic), libcinnamon-control-center1:i386 (2.2.11-3, automatic), cinnamon-control-center-data:i386 (2.2.11-3, automatic), gir1.2-coglpango-1.0:i386 (1.18.2-2, automatic), libnemo-extension1:i386 (2.2.4-1, automatic), gir1.2-xkl-1.0:i386 (5.4-0ubuntu1, automatic), libwayland-cursor0:i386 (1.5.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxcb-shape0-dev:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-gkbd-3.0:i386 (3.6.0-0ubuntu2, automatic)
    Upgrade: libpython2.7-minimal:i386 (2.7.4-2ubuntu3, 2.7.8-7), totem-common:i386 (3.6.3-0ubuntu6, 3.10.1-1ubuntu6), libnettle4:i386 (2.4-3, 2.7.1-3), gstreamer1.0-clutter:i386 (2.0.2-0ubuntu1, 2.0.12-1), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (1.0.6-1, 1.4.1-1), python2.7:i386 (2.7.4-2ubuntu3, 2.7.8-7), libgmp10:i386 (5.0.5+dfsg-2ubuntu3, 6.0.0+dfsg-4), libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (2.7.4-2ubuntu3, 2.7.8-7), libxcb-render0:i386 (1.8.1-2ubuntu2, 1.10-2ubuntu1), libgtk-3-bin:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu8, 3.12.2-0ubuntu6), libxklavier16:i386 (5.2.1-1ubuntu2, 5.4-0ubuntu1), libglapi-mesa:i386 (9.1.1-0ubuntu3, 10.2.6-1ubuntu3), libxcb-xfixes0:i386 (1.8.1-2ubuntu2, 1.10-2ubuntu1), libxcb-shape0:i386 (1.8.1-2ubuntu2, 1.10-2ubuntu1), python-minimal:i386 (2.7.4-0ubuntu1, 2.7.8-1), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.43-0ubuntu1, 2.4.56-1), libpixman-1-0:i386 (0.28.2-0ubuntu1, 0.32.4-1ubuntu1), libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:i386 (1.4.2-0ubuntu2, 1.5.2-2), libgtk-3-0:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu8, 3.12.2-0ubuntu6), libegl1-mesa:i386 (9.1.1-0ubuntu3, 10.2.6-1ubuntu3), liborc-0.4-0:i386 (0.4.17-1, 0.4.22-1), libgcrypt11:i386 (1.5.0-3ubuntu2.1, 1.5.4-2ubuntu1), libtotem0:i386 (3.6.3-0ubuntu6, 3.10.1-1ubuntu6), gir1.2-atspi-2.0:i386 (2.8.0-1, 2.10.2.is.2.10.1-0ubuntu1), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.43-0ubuntu1, 2.4.56-1), libdrm-dev:i386 (2.4.43-0ubuntu1, 2.4.56-1), libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 (0.15.2-0ubuntu1, 1.0.2-1), libpython-stdlib:i386 (2.7.4-0ubuntu1, 2.7.8-1), libclutter-1.0-0:i386 (1.12.2-0ubuntu3, 1.18.4-1), libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 (9.1.1-0ubuntu3, 10.2.6-1ubuntu3), libsoup2.4-1:i386 (2.40.3-0ubuntu1, 2.46.0-2ubuntu1), totem-mozilla:i386 (3.6.3-0ubuntu6, 3.10.1-1ubuntu6), libegl1-mesa-drivers:i386 (9.1.1-0ubuntu3, 10.2.6-1ubuntu3), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.43-0ubuntu1, 2.4.56-1), totem:i386 (3.6.3-0ubuntu6, 3.10.1-1ubuntu6), libgles2-mesa:i386 (9.1.1-0ubuntu3, 10.2.6-1ubuntu3), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.43-0ubuntu1, 2.4.56-1), liblcms2-2:i386 (2.4-0ubuntu3, 2.6-3ubuntu1), libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (1.0.6-1, 1.4.1-1), totem-plugins:i386 (3.6.3-0ubuntu6, 3.10.1-1ubuntu6), libclutter-gst-2.0-0:i386 (2.0.2-0ubuntu1, 2.0.12-1), accountsservice:i386 (0.6.29-1ubuntu8, 0.6.37-1ubuntu9), empathy-common:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu4, 3.8.6-0ubuntu12), libgail-3-0:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu8, 3.12.2-0ubuntu6), libgcr-3-1:i386 (3.6.2-0ubuntu2, 3.12.2-1), libatspi2.0-0:i386 (2.8.0-1, 2.10.2.is.2.10.1-0ubuntu1), libaccountsservice0:i386 (0.6.29-1ubuntu8, 0.6.37-1ubuntu9), gir1.2-totem-1.0:i386 (3.6.3-0ubuntu6, 3.10.1-1ubuntu6), python2.7-minimal:i386 (2.7.4-2ubuntu3, 2.7.8-7), libtiff5:i386 (4.0.2-4ubuntu2, 4.0.3-10), libpython2.7:i386 (2.7.4-2ubuntu3, 2.7.8-7), python:i386 (2.7.4-0ubuntu1, 2.7.8-1), mesa-common-dev:i386 (9.1.1-0ubuntu3, 10.2.6-1ubuntu3), libxcb1-dev:i386 (1.8.1-2ubuntu2, 1.10-2ubuntu1), libxcb1:i386 (1.8.1-2ubuntu2, 1.10-2ubuntu1), libwayland0:i386 (1.0.5-0ubuntu1, 1.5.0-1ubuntu1), libp11-kit0:i386 (0.14-1, 0.20.2-5), libcairo2:i386 (1.12.14-0ubuntu1, 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1), libgtk-3-common:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu8, 3.12.2-0ubuntu6), python-imaging:i386 (1.1.7+2.0.0-1, 2.5.3-1), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (9.1.1-0ubuntu3, 10.2.6-1ubuntu3), at-spi2-core:i386 (2.8.0-1, 2.10.2.is.2.10.1-0ubuntu1)
    Remove: account-plugin-yahoo:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu4), account-plugin-jabber:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu4), mcp-account-manager-uoa:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu4), libcogl-pango12:i386 (1.14.0-0ubuntu1), python-imaging-compat:i386 (1.1.7+2.0.0-1), account-plugin-salut:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu4), libcogl12:i386 (1.14.0-0ubuntu1), empathy:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu4), nautilus-sendto-empathy:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu4), account-plugin-aim:i386 (3.6.4-0ubuntu4)
    End-Date: 2014-09-16  08:45:17
```

Comment: Changing your source list to point it to a major release is not the correct way to upgrade ubuntu.

Comment: @xangua how to use ubuntu utopic?

Comment: Utopic is currently in development and not supported here.

Comment: @xangua so how to upgrade to trusy?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issues by remove all new installed packages, install all removed packages, downgrade all updated packages in section , and now i back to unity.